# How do I get the next node id/name along the path the agent is moving?

Tags: path, anylogic, agent

Assume that an agent is moving from Node1 to Node3 in the following network:
Node1 - PathA - Node2 - PathB- Node3
How do I access the next node the agent will pass?

The actual task it for bus agents to move along the yellow paths and pickup/drop off passengers and crews at the corresponding stands (nodes) - one of the tasks requires me to acquire the "next node".

[image: nodes and paths at airport]

Comment: Can you please post a picture of the network?
Additionally, are you generally interested in knowing his next destination given his current location and final destination? Or only on the route from Node1 to Node3.
Are you interested in the reverse route from Node3 to Node1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full control of path-finding and nodes, check this tutorial. Fair warning: this is quite advanced and goes well beyond AnyLogic basics: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2022/8/6/taking-control-of-your-network-agent-based-pathfinding

Comment: Hi Benjamin - fantastic, thank you for your input and the work on the videos.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a destination node, the only thing you can access once your agent starts moving is the destination position using `getTargetX()` for instance.

Nevertheless, AnyLogic doesn't give you access to the set of nodes the agent will use on its movement.